# Using curl with gnu-parallel or xarg, to loop through ports 1-65535 in bash

Tags: bash, curl, xargs, gnu-parallel

I need to make a curl call, to request a banner (timeout 5 curl -I ip:port command, with 5s timeout) for all the ports of an ip and save the results into a single file, in the following format (space delimited):
"port number" "second line of the pulled banner"

What would be the correct bash script to do the job?
Also, what's the reasonable amount of the parallel jobs to run, on the 2gb 2-core Kvm Vps?

P.S. I know the are scripts like nmap, to do the job fast, but, they often fail in pulling the banners, where as the curl command gives me 100% result, each time.

Comment: What's a *"pulled banner"* please?

Comment: cur -I command pulls the banner, if one exists, which will contain several lines. I'm only interested in the second line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
parallel 'r=$(timeout 5 curl -l 192.168.0.1:{} | sed -ne "2p"); echo "{} $r"'  ::: {1..65535}
```

Comment: Thanks, this kind of works, but runs the single instance of curl. The whole purpose of using parallels is to speed up the process, by splitting the ports range, in between several curl process running in parallel. Perhaps, I wasn't clear enough, in my original post.

Comment: No, that will run as many `curl`s as you have CPU cores. If you want more, say 32, use `parallel -j 32 ...`

Comment: You can't have 65536 ports open at once, but you can probably run a couple hundred processes in parallel.

Comment: @tripleee i just ran about 20,000 threads simultaneously doing network tasks on a debian linux VPS with 9GB ram and 4 cores. (that said, the VPS has been specifically tuned to allow running huge amount of threads simultaneously)

Comment: Thanks! My bad, it does work as intended. Running -j 50 with success.

Comment: @hanshanrik The choke point is the number of open network ports.